# Some accounts return a blank response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Really odd situation that just started to occur. I have an App Token that's valid and can receive data on certain accounts. The problem is that it's not always consistent, some account work perfectly, but some are returning blank responses. I've never seen anything like it.

Does anyone have any ideas? If I fudge my access token a bit, it'll respond with the correct errors, but it seems like everything correct and I get nothing.

My endpoint is /account_id/posts?access_token=xxxxxXXXXxxxxXXXxXxxx

Comment: What is a "blank response"?

Comment: {

    "data": [ ]

}

Comment: After a couple of different valid App Tokens, it seems like there's something odd with the account I'm trying to pull in. Is there a way users can prevent access to their account information through the Graph API? It seems like I should be getting an error code if that's the case.

Comment: Even more strange, my user token is working fine (when retrieving from the access token tool) https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

Just with this one account, and just with the app token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be related to the page having some type of demographic restrictions enabled.  When this happens a user token is required to pull some information so FB can check to see if the restriction is applicable.

Comment: Dustin, you are correct. The problem is that there's some sort of restriction on that page account. The problem is - how do I access the data as an App? Is there some sort of white list the page has access to that add the app to it?

Comment: You would need access to a user token without those restrictions or possibly a page token granted with the manage pages permission.  I've not tried the 2nd approach but would probably work as it's the pages own token.  You will need to be careful with the information you are displaying doesn't show anything that would be frowned on by FB.